# Why am I getting this error from ggplot: Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't figure out why this warning is occurring. It generates a lot of spurious error messages in the console as my app is making graphs.

ggplot2 version 3.3.6.9000.

Full text of the error:

```
Warning message:
In structure(in_domain, pos = match(in_domain, breaks)) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
```

Here is an MRE:

```
library(ggplot2)

facet<-rep(c("Sample 1","Sample 2","Sample 3","Sample 4","Sample 5"),20)
num_data<-rnorm(100)

data<-data.frame(cbind(facet,num_data))
data$num_data<-as.numeric(data$num_data)

names(data)<-c("ID","Data")

plot_data<-data

leg_names<-c("Data"="red")

p<-ggplot(plot_data,aes(x=Data))+
  scale_color_manual(values=leg_names)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=leg_names)

p<-p+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill="Data"))+
  labs(y="Count")

p
```

Comment: The error seems to be caused by ```scale_color_manual(values=leg_names)```

Comment: I tested your example and there is no error message. perhaps, try the official cran ggplot package?

Comment: Hunh, that did it. Thanks! I'll let the devs know about it.

Comment: Where did you get that particular version if not from CRAN?  Diving into places like github can lead to non-released mainline code.